# installing windows on VMWare with shared DVD drive

Tags: vmware

I have a mac mini without an attached dvd drive. I want to install Windows via VMWare Fusion (3). I have the disc in my tower, but VMWare doesn't recognize it (although I can browse to it in my finder). Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the VMWare settings menu, there are options on how to use an optical drive. Pick share physical drive (as opposed to iso file or none).